# ionic 4 splashscreen still showing white screen after removing splashscreen cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i'm trying to hide splash screen.
i tried two mathods
First i changed my preference to the following code

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
```

Second i remove the splashscreen plugin

these remove the splashscreen but a white screen still showing for three seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the splash screen but it is not a good idea as it will result in a black or white screen to be visible instead.

Every Ionic / Cordova App simply needs a bit of time to initialize and will not render anything on the screen until it is ready. Once the initialization is done the App is ready to use and you can remove the splash screen. If you check `src/app.component.ts` you will find the following line:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.splashScreen.hide();
});
```

The preferences you mention above simply give you additional control over the appearance of the splash screen.

Comment: but how to insert custom splash screen( created with html code) insted of image? 
i'm using div tag in app.component this shows after whitescreen. is there any way to use html element in default splashscreen???